# How can set a Qwidget inside a QGraphicsWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

Is it possible that a `QGraphicsWidget` be a parent for `QWidget`? I have a `QGraphicsItem` and I want to add a `QWidget` inside this item, How can I set a `QWidget` in a `QGraphicsItem` or `QGraphicsWidget` that is a child of `QGraphicsItem`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QGraphicsWidget` is basically a `QGraphicsItem` for `QWidget`s ... it provides a layout you can use so it should be no problem at all

use:
`QGraphicsScene::addWidget( QWidget * widget, Qt::WindowFlags wFlags = 0 )`

Answer (score 4):

QWidget and QGraphicsWidget are very different. However, the QGraphics system provides a QGraphicsProxyWidget for embedding QWidget and QWidget-based items in a QGraphicsScene.

You can directly create the QGraphicsProxyWidget and call the function setWidget, before adding the QGraphicsProxyWidget to your QGraphicsScene: -

```
QGraphicsScene* pScene = new QGraphicsScene;
QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget;
QGraphicsProxyWidget* pProxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(parent); // parent can be NULL
pProxy->setWidget(pWidget);
pScene->addItem(pProxy);
```

The proxy widget can now be moved, scaled etc in the scene and the functionality of its QWidget will have signals passed through to it to work as expected.

Alternatively, the QGraphicsScene contains a shortcut function addWidget, which internally creates the QGraphicsProxyWidget for you and returns it from the function: -

```
QGraphicsProxyWidget* pProxy = pScene->addWidget(pWidget);
```